# How can I break out of ssh when it locks?

Tags: ssh

I frequently ssh into my box at home from school, but usually when I change classes and my computer suspends, the pipe will be broken. However, ssh simply locks up - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> have no effect.

It's annoying to have to restart my terminal, and even more annoying to have to close and re-create a new screen window.

So my question, is there an easy way to make ssh die properly (i.e. when the pipe fails "normally" it will exit with a message about a broken pipe)? Or do I have to figure out what the PID is and manually kill it?

Comment: If I got disconnected with an active SSH session, it freezes. I just kill it and start a new session. No information is lost because I use GNU screen.

Comment: Me too - screen is the best. But it's still annoying to have to `screen -x` :P

Comment: [mosh](mosh.mit.edu) is a neat alternative to avoid this problem. It "stays connected" even with intermittent internet connectivity.

Comment: @jaynp The drawback of me using mosh (since two minutes ago) is that I don't know how to disconnect it. I'm using a tmux+irssi session on a remote host (as an IRC bouncer, sort of) and I do want to disconnect sometimes (while keeping the tmux+irssi running) and that I did with <enter>+~+. using SSH but won't work using mosh.

Answer (score 641, accepted):

Normal keys are forwarded over the `ssh` session, so none of those will work. Instead, use the escape sequences. To kill the current session hit subsequently <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>.

(Keep in mind that in international keyboards where `~` is set to be a composing character, you have to hit it twice: <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>)

More of these escape sequences can be listed with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>?</kbd>:

```
Supported escape sequences:
     ~.   - terminate connection (and any multiplexed sessions)
     ~B   - send a BREAK to the remote system
     ~C   - open a command line
     ~R   - request rekey
     ~V/v - decrease/increase verbosity (LogLevel)
     ~^Z  - suspend ssh
     ~#   - list forwarded connections
     ~&   - background ssh (when waiting for connections to terminate)
     ~?   - this message
     ~~   - send the escape character by typing it twice
(Note that escapes are only recognized immediately after newline.)
```

You can close the list of Escape sequences by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Notice that because hitting <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> causes `ssh` to send the `~` instead of intercepting it, you can address *N* nested `ssh` connections by hitting <kbd>~</kbd> *N* times. (This only applies to <kbd>~</kbd>s that directly follow an <kbd>Enter</kbd>.) That is to say that <kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> terminates an `ssh` session 5 layers deep and keeps the other 4 intact.

Comment: For keyboard layouts where `~` is a [dead key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key), the key sequence is `Enter` `~` `Space` `.`.

Comment: I've [added](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/29952/2) more of the escape sequences which might be useful. :)

Comment: Note that you need to uncomment the line `EscapeChar ~` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (or `~/.ssh/ssh_config` if you prefer).

Comment: Anyone know how to terminate a frozen SSH session from /inside another SSH session/?

Comment: @Hitechcomputergeek `Enter` `~` `~` `.` Since `~` `~` sends a literal `~` through your SSH session, the second SSH session will receive it as a single tilde and will interpret the `.` as part of the escape. To send to the 5th nested ssh session, just use 5 tildes in your escape sequence.

Comment: life changing ;)

Comment: jeez, I've been using ssh for like 20 years, and I only just found this out!!!

Comment: How have I never heard of this before? These escape sequences can even change port forwards on the fly, which I need somewhat frequently. My mind is totally blown

Answer (score 69):

You may also want to setup application-level **keep-alives** for SSH to *prevent* it from freezing on connection issues. My `~/.ssh/config` contains this:

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 15
# ServerAliveCountMax 3
```

This makes ssh client send application-level keep-alives every 15 seconds. Whenever three of them fail consecutively (the default of `ServerAliveCountMax`), the client considers the connection as hung and closes it.

Opposed to the other option `TCPKeepAlive`, this is checked within the encrypted channel and is not spoofable.

---

It is being noted that those keep-alives also help to, uhm, keep *long-idling* connections alive, i.e. prevent you from having [half-closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_half-open) tcp sessions hanging for hours untouched.

I highly recommend turning this feature on if you run into this regularly, but you should also know about the slight security risk it may impose. A [known-plaintext attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) might become easier if the attacker knows the interval and contents of an idle connection. This might be the reasons for why it isn't enabled by default.

Comment: Security reasons. You could go have drink and leave ssh sessio opened and your lab partner who you have worked with in the past 20 years might use your session to hijack the server and destroy it... while you were drinking in your 10 minute break.

Comment: @CYREX, eh? And how can turned off by default option prevent you from having unfair lab partners? `%)`

Comment: @ulidtko: Is there any reason for not setting `ServerAliveInterval` to 1 so that a lost connection is detected immediately?

Comment: I've [improved the post](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/29967/3) with my knowledge about it together with other 'fixes'. I think it is not *the* answer to the question as it is more about preventing rather than fixing an already broken one.

Comment: @gertvdijk: Thank you. For me, it works even without the `Host` line. Also, "Modern ciphers such as Advanced Encryption Standard are not currently susceptible to known-plaintext attacks." (from the link you added)...

Comment: @user946850 Yeah the `Host` line is actually just restricting, but if you have some in your config file already, then you'll need this to match them all at once. And yes, you're correct most ciphers aren't vulnerable that much, but it's a very general recommendation not to send *known* (or predictable) data in a *regular pattern* if you care about security in encryption.

Comment: you can also replace SSH with Mosh (mobile shell). Mosh connects to the server via SSH, but then establishes an UDP based channel that is resiliant against connection problems. Mosh has also a local echo, so you can see what you are typing, even if the server is not answering. When the keystrokes are delivered, Mosh marks the echoed text. https://mosh.mit.edu/

Comment: Re security: that's where `RekeyLimit` option comes in, or `~R` (manually initiated key re-exchange)

Answer (score 47):

As noted in geekosaur's answer, the escape sequence `~.` will terminate the connection.

The full list of escape sequences and what they do can be displayed by typing `~?`:

```
Supported escape sequences:
  ~.  - terminate connection (and any multiplexed sessions)
  ~B  - send a BREAK to the remote system
  ~C  - open a command line
  ~R  - Request rekey (SSH protocol 2 only)
  ~^Z - suspend ssh
  ~#  - list forwarded connections
  ~&  - background ssh (when waiting for connections to terminate)
  ~?  - this message
  ~~  - send the escape character by typing it twice
(Note that escapes are only recognized immediately after newline.)
```

Comment: How do I close the list of escape sequences?

Comment: You dont, after it prints the escape sequence list, its ready to accept the  next one.