# How do I suspend over ssh?

Tags: server, ssh, suspend, dbus

I guess this question is pretty much the same as [How to configure dbus to allow ssh-user to suspend server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21586/how-to-configure-dbus-to-allow-ssh-user-to-suspend-server); except I wanted to formulate it better.

Assume I have an Ubuntu server running nonstop, let's call it `MyServer`. Let's say then, I have another PC on the same local network as `MyServer`, let's call it `MyLocalPC`.

`MyLocalPC` is then kept in suspend, unless it is turned on via `wakeonlan` by `MyServer`. This part of the process works perfectly for me: I can log in via `ssh` to `MyServer`, and on the `MyServer` ssh prompt I can issue `wakeonlan`, and `MyLocalPC` wakes up - great.

Then, however, as soon as I'm done working with `MyLocalPC`, I'd like to put it into suspend again. The problem is as follows - I can put the machine in suspend easy, if I ssh into `MyLocalPC` first via `ssh`:

```
[MyServer]$ ssh MyLocalPC
[MyLocalPC]$ dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.PowerManagement --type=method_call --print-reply --reply-timeout=2000 /org/freedesktop/PowerManagement org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Suspend
```

This will suspend `MyLocalPC` - but will also block the `ssh` exiting properly, and eventually the `ssh` to `MyServer` ends up frozen. I try to get tricky and issue something like this:

```
[MyServer]$ ssh MyLocalPC "dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.PowerManagement --type=method_call --print-reply --reply-timeout=2000 /org/freedesktop/PowerManagement org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Suspend"
Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: /bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
```

Then I read somewhere `DISPLAY` variable should be defined - but that fails too:

```
[MyServer]$ ssh MyLocalPC "DISPLAY=:0 dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.PowerManagement --type=method_call --print-reply --reply-timeout=2000 /org/freedesktop/PowerManagement  org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Suspend"
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PowerManagement was not provided by any .service files
```

So does anyone know how can I issue a suspend to `MyLocalPC`, without the `ssh` connection to `MyServer` freezing?

Answer (score 3):

Just type `<enter>~&` (that's three keystrokes: enter, squggle, ampersand) and ssh will go into the background, and eventually timeout by itself.  That's good if you want to just abandon an interactive session in a case like this.

Or, alternatively, put that into a shell script on MyLocalPC and connect in a way that will background the connection:

```
ssh -f MyLocalPC go-to-sleep
```

Comment: Thanks @poolie for the answer - will have to report back with what I ended up choosing, I just wanted to +1 for now :) Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

For me the simplest is to use the `at` command:

```
echo 'pm-suspend' | sudo at now + 2 minutes
```

Then disconnect from SSH session.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the X11 forwarding using `ssh -Y`. Alternatively, use `at now + 2 minutes` to run the command only once (see `man at` for more information).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Adam Byrtek - good info on X11 forwarding..

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old question, but on Ubuntu 22.04, I've been using

`sudo systemctl suspend && exit`

to suspend the machine and immediately exit the SSH connection.

Comment: It may have been a new answer to an old question, but it really is the best way for a modern system.

Answer (score 1):

set a cron job for 2 minutes in the future and disconnect

Comment: Hi @aking1012 - thanks for that, I'll give it a try and report back.... Cheers!

Comment: `at` would be a better choice than `cron` if you just need a single job to run a bit later, or even better just `sleep 2m && blah`.

Comment: @poolie - good point

Answer (score 0):

[How can I break out of ssh when it locks?](https://askubuntu.com/q/29942/30266)
There are many valid solutions.
One has been mentioned by poolie; I have set up a [keep-alive timeout](https://askubuntu.com/a/29967/30266) on my system that will auto-suspend hanging SSH sessions by adding the following to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 5
ServerAliveCountMax 4
```

Works also after suspending the remote machine.